# iSeries DB2 - SQL GUI Tool

Tags: sql, graphical-user-interface, ibm-midrange, db2

Can someone suggest a good free Database tool with SQL support for connection to an iSeries.  Currently I am using the green screen and it is quite frustrating.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean a bit? Do you mean something like WRKDBF or WRKQRY or do you want an app on your computer similar to phpMyAdmin or SQL Server Management Studio? I'm thinking the latter, but clarification might help people to better answer your question.

Comment: An app on my computer (Windows XP), much like sqlDbx (http://www.sqldbx.com/) but free for commercial use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my own research SQuirreL SQL is the best open source GUI client for the iSeries.  It tried it out today it it worked nicely, code completion, syntax highlighting etc.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend [DbVisualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/) with the [IBM Toolbox/JTOpen](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/i-javatoolbox/) database driver.  You can also use it to connect to almost any other database as well.  It's cross platform and runs on Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows.

There is a [Free edition](https://www.dbvis.com/features/) edition for commercial and non-commercial use.

[image: DbVisualizer Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

IBM provides IBM Data Studio at no charge. http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/optim/data-studio/

Answer (score 0):

[IBM i Client Access](http://www.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/) does a good job with most of the requirements.